# Wrapping a text on image and div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to find a way to use a img simulating the background: cover property but without using object-fit, since is not supported in some browsers.

Also, i'm trying to wrap a text around this image and make a block above it.

**The problem is** the text is creating a margin between the block and the image and i don't want that.. Does anyone know a way to solve it?

**The html:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="">
  </div>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</p>
<div class="image-box"></div>
```

**The css:**

```
.container{
    width:700px;
}

.image{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;     
}

.image img{
    float:left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 225px;
    object-fit: cover;
    position: relative;
}

.container p{
    font-size:20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: justify;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
}

.image-box{
    height:50px;
    width: 300px;
    line-height: 2.3em;
    font-weight: 700;
    background: #D8DFE3;
    text-align: center; 
}
```

And here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/0hspa3wh/2/

Comment: What is the purpose of the "image-box" div? If it's related to the image, wouldn't it make sense to put it in the "image" div ***with*** the actual image.

Comment: do you need it to be like here? http://jsfiddle.net/0hspa3wh/4/

Comment: It'll be a comment link, if I put the image-box in the img div it will overlay the img, or am I wrong?
Yes, that's what i need!

Answer (score 0):

pretty much utilized `display: inline-block;` and the html structure of `divs`

```css
.container{
    width:700px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.left{
    margin-right: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.image img{
    width: 300px;
    height: 225px;
    object-fit: cover;
    position: relative;
}

.container .text{
    font-size:20px;
    width: 370px;
    text-align: justify;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.image-box{
    height:50px;
    width: 300px;
    line-height: 2.3em;
    font-weight: 700;
    background: #D8DFE3;
    text-align: center; 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="image">
            <img src=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="image-box">This block shouldnt have this margin up</div>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>    

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

by using the grid in CSS you can make it if I well understood what you wanted :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="">
      </div>
      <div class="image-box">This block shouldnt have this margin up</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>
        Your text
        </p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Here is the JSfiddle updated : http://jsfiddle.net/0hspa3wh/3/